# Not able to access Sub-Class instance variable that has been assigned to a SuperClass Reference

Tags: java, variables, inheritance, subclass, superclass

This has been bugging me for a while. I am new to serious OOps concepts and came across. Here's what I have:

Class ape:

```
public class ape {
String name;

public String getBehavior() {

    return "I am apeshit";

   }

}
```

Class humano:

```
public class humano extends ape {
public String name;

public humano(String namevalue) {
    name = namevalue;
}

public String getBehavior() {
    return "I am a :" + name;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
  }

}
```

Class neandarthal:

```
public class neandarthal extends ape {

String name;

public neandarthal(String name) {
    super.name = name;
}

public String getBehavior() {
    return "I am  a :" + name;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
  }

}
```

Species_Factory Class:

public class species_factory {

```
static ape ap = null;

static ape getSpecies(String name) {
    if (name == "humano") {
        return new humano(name);
    }

    if (name == "neandarthal") {
        return new neandarthal(name);
    }

    else {
        return ap;
    }

}
```

}

And Finally the main class species:

```
public class species {
public static void main(String args[]) {
    ape a1 = species_factory.getSpecies("humano");
    ape a2 = species_factory.getSpecies("neandarthal");
    System.out.println(a1.name);
    System.out.println(a2.name);
    System.out.println(a1.getBehavior());
    System.out.println(a2.getBehavior());
    System.out.println(a1.getClass().getSuperclass().getName());

  }

}
```

The output:

```
null
neandarthal
I am a :humano
I am  a :null
ape
```

The query I have is regarding the null value. Basically when I try to display `System.out.println(a1.name)`. I am seeing `null`. Why is this?

I see that I am getting the value `I am a :humano` in the third line, which means that the value I pass for the string variable `name` is getting stored in the `humano` instance.

But why is it not displayed when I try to display the same variable using the statement `System.out.println(a1.name)`?

Sorry might be a silly question with my lack of understanding..but will be very grateful for a reply.

Comment: Can you show what you did in the species_factory class?

Comment: What is `species_factory.getSpecies`? Please create a [mcve] with all the code necessary to reproduce the problem.

Comment: Why do you have the subclasses redeclaring `name`? It shadows the one they inherit, and is probably part of the problem, but we can't say without seeing `species_factory` and that MCVE John Kugelman talked about.

Comment: Adding now: 
    public class species_factory {

 static ape ap = null;

 static ape getSpecies(String name) {
  if (name == "humano") {
   return new humano(name);
  }

  if (name == "neandarthal") {
   return new neandarthal(name);
  }

  else {
   return ap;
  }

 }

}

Answer (score 2):

> Basically when I try to display "System.out.println(a1.name)" I am seeing null. Why is this?

The main problem here is that by redeclaring `name` in `humano` and `neandarthal`, you're *shadowing* the `name` field that exists in `ape`. That means that the objects created by `humano` and `neandarthal` have **two** `name` fields: The one defined by `ape`, and a separate one they define for themselves. Then in the code, you're being very inconsistent about which `name` field you use.

You almost certainly want to remove the `name` declarations in `humano` and `neandarthal` (and then use `this.`, not `super.`, on `name`), so you're using the field declared in `ape`.

The specific reasons for what you're seeing are:

- The first line (`"null"`): `humano` assigns to its *own* `name` field, but when you use `a1.name` in your `main`, since `a1` is declared as an `ape`, it's using the `name`field in `ape` (which is still `null`, nothing has ever assigned to it).
- The second line (`"neandarthal"`): `neandarthal` assigns to `ape`'s `name` field (`super.name = ...`), not its own. Since `a2` is declared as `ape`, `a2.ape` uses that and you see the string you assigned.
- The third line (`"I am a :humano"`): `humano`'s `getBehavior` uses its own `name` field, not `ape`'s, so you see what the constructor assigned to it.
- The fourth line (`"I am  a :null"`): `neandarthal`'s `getBehavior` uses its *own* `name` field, which is still `null` because nothing has ever assigned to it).
- The fifth line (`"ape"`): I don't think you're confused about this, but `humano`'s superclass is `ape`.

Comment: Thanks T.J. Crowder. That explains it!